# How to code a nested repeated measures model in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to figure out how to formulate a mixed effects model and code it in R for a while now. I have been reading a lot about mixed models, but I can’t find an example that seems similar to what I have. My supervisor recently suggested that I’d ask for help from the online community. I am new to this forum, so please let me know if this isn’t the right place to ask or if information is missing. 
Here is how my experiment is set up. I am investigating the impacts of different leaf litter treatment and canopy types on moss growth in a field experiment over time. We selected three areas (blocks A, B, C) in which we identified adjacent spruce and birch stands (forest type treatment, 6 stands). In each stand, we set up 5 plots (30 plots), in which we placed 4 moss transplants (this is my sampling unit, n=120). Each transplant was assigned to 1 of 4 leaf litter treatments (coded as ADD, AMB, CON, EXC). I tagged 10 individual moss shoots within each transplant and then measured their size in 2013, 2014 and 2015. I am taking the average moss shoot size per transplant as my response variable. I am expecting that leaf litter treatment will interact with forest type, and that the degree of impact of each main effect and the interaction on moss size will vary in the three sampling time (e.g. only an effect of Forest Type in 2013, both main effects in 2014, and then the interaction in 2015). 
Here is what the data looks like.

```
    df=data.frame(Year = as.ordered(rep(2013:2015, each=120)),
ForestType = as.factor(rep(rep(c('Spruce', 'Birch'), each=60), 3)),
Block=as.factor(rep(rep(c('A','B','C'), each=20), 6)),
Plot=as.factor(rep(rep(1:5, each=4),18)),
Treatment=as.factor(rep(c('ADD', 'AMB', 'CON', 'EXC'), 90)))

# Create unique IDs for each of the 30 plots and 120 moss transplants
cols <- c('ForestType', 'Block', 'Plot')
cols2 <- c('ForestType', 'Block', 'Plot', 'Treatment')
df$plot.id <- as.factor(do.call(paste, c(df[cols], sep=".")))
df$transplant.id <- as.factor(do.call(paste, c(df[cols2], sep=".")))

# Created a variable with a similar structure to the original one
df$MossSize=c(1.5   ,   1.4 ,  1.2  ,  1.6  ,  1.5  ,  1.4  ,  1.9  ,  1.7  ,  2.2  ,  1.6  ,  1.7  ,  2.3  ,  1.6  ,  1.7  ,  1.4  ,  2.0  ,  2.1  ,   3.3 ,  2.7  ,  1.1  ,  3.1  ,  2.2  ,  2.7  ,  2.3  ,  2.4  ,  2.0  ,  2.1  ,  2.6  ,  2.6  ,  2.1  ,  2.8  ,  1.7  ,  2.1  ,   2.2 ,  3.6  ,  1.8  ,  2.7  ,  2.5  ,  3.1  ,  2.9  ,  3.5  ,2.2    ,  1.5  ,  2.3  ,  2.0  ,  1.4  ,  1.9  ,  1.8  ,  2.8  ,  2.9  ,  2.5  ,  2.6  ,  2.1  ,  2.0  ,  1.6  ,  2.3  ,  3.0  ,  3.9  ,  2.4  ,  3.6  ,  3.2  ,  2.3  ,  4.5  ,  2.7  ,  2.1  ,  2.1  ,  2.2  ,  1.7  , 1.8   ,  2.0  ,  2.3  ,  2.3  ,  2.2  ,  3.5  ,  3.7  ,  2.4  ,  2.1  ,  2.3  ,  2.9  ,  2.0  ,  2.6  ,  2.5  ,  3.4  ,  3.3  ,  2.5  ,  2.8  ,  4.1  ,  3.5  ,  2.9  ,  3.2  ,  2.5  ,  3.2  ,  2.7  ,  2.7  ,  3.8  ,  3.6  ,  3.0  ,  3.3  ,  2.9  ,  1.8  ,  3.3  ,  2.8  , 4.8   ,  3.8  ,  2.5  ,  2.5  ,  3.9  ,  3.0  ,  4.5  ,  3.0  ,  3.1  ,  3.0  , 2.7   ,  3.5  ,  3.6  ,  2.9  ,  2.9  ,  3.6  ,  2.6  ,  3.0  ,  3.3  ,  3.2  ,  2.9  ,  3.5  ,  2.3  ,  2.1  ,  3.8  ,  3.9  ,  4.3  ,  2.4  ,  3.6  ,  6.6  ,  1.7  ,  6.2  ,  4.7  ,  4.0  ,  3.1  ,  4.0  ,  5.9  ,  2.7  ,  4.7  ,  5.9  ,  6.5  ,  5.0  ,  5.1  ,  5.7  ,  7.1  ,  6.2  ,  4.2  ,  3.4  ,  4.9  ,  4.7  ,  3.1,  2.7    , 6.8   ,  4.0  ,  4.2  ,  3.9  ,  5.9  ,  7.1  ,  5.3  ,  4.6  ,  3.7  ,  4.2  ,  3.2  ,  2.2  ,  5.8  ,  5.2  ,  4.8  ,  3.9  ,  5.4  ,  7.3  ,  4.7  ,  4.5  ,  5.3  ,  5.8  ,  5.9  ,  3.8  ,  6.5  ,  8.3  ,  7.2  ,  5.9  ,  9.9  ,  5.9  ,  3.4  ,3.4    ,  3.8  ,  3.3  ,  4.6  ,  3.0  ,  3.6  ,  4.1  ,  2.6  ,  8.0  ,  9.1  ,  6.3  ,  4.1  ,  6.7  ,  9.0  ,  5.1  ,  4.4  ,  6.9  ,  6.9  ,  8.2  ,  3.8  ,  6.1  ,  8.8  ,  8.8  ,  5.3  ,  8.9  ,  7.5  ,  7.0  ,  4.7  ,6.7    ,  8.9  ,  11.3 ,  6.0,  7.2    ,  6.3  ,  4.7  ,  6.8  ,  8.1  ,  9.1  ,  10.2,  4.5   ,  5.8  , 5.9   ,  7.1  ,  13.0,  7.2   ,  9.1  ,  9.0  ,  6.0  ,  7.9  ,  9.3  ,  3.8  ,  5.8  ,  9.0  ,  7.7  ,  6.3  ,  3.4  ,  4.9  ,  6.4  ,  7.5  ,  3.8  ,  3.1  ,  10.4 ,  5.8  ,  5.5  ,  2.9  ,  9.0  ,  10.4 ,  1.6  ,  5.4  ,  6.6  ,  6.2  ,  4.6  ,  8.7  ,  10.0 ,  4.7  ,  5.2  ,  12.4 ,  10.4 ,  8.6  ,  7.9  ,  10.5 ,  14.9 ,  10.3 ,  4.7  ,  4.8  ,  9.7  ,  6.6  ,  2.8  ,  2.4  ,  9.5  ,  5.6  ,  5.1  ,  4.9  ,  11.5 ,  9.8  ,  6.8  ,  6.8  ,  5.5  ,  7.5  ,  3.1  ,  3.2  ,  8.7  ,  7.4  ,  5.8  ,  4.5  ,  10.9 ,  11.1 ,  4.6  ,  6.5  ,  7.5  ,  10.3 ,  8.3  ,  6.1  ,  9.3  ,  11.6 ,  9.5  ,  10.2 ,  16.1 ,  10.4,  4.4   ,  4.5  ,  6.9  ,  4.6  ,  4.5  ,  4.1  ,  6.1  ,  5.0  ,  4.2  ,  9.3  ,  15.4 ,  8.6  ,  3.9  ,  11.7 ,  13.3 ,  9.2  ,  6.3  ,  9.7  ,  11.8 ,  14.6 ,  4.9  ,  9.4  ,  15.4 ,  17.6 ,  6.8  ,  16.7 ,  9.3  ,  11.8 ,  4.8  ,  10.5 ,  13.2 ,  15.2 ,  5.9  ,  12.6 ,  13.1 ,  9.3  ,  9.9  ,  13.4 ,  10.7 ,  18.9 ,  5.5  ,  8.7  ,  14.0 ,  16.3 ,  12.3 ,  16.7,  14.0  ,  15.0 ,  6.2  ,  17.9 ,  18.2 ,  8.3  ,  8.7  ,  17.8 ,  12.5 ,  9.9)
df$logMossSize=log(MossSize+1)

head(df)
```

I am planning to use either lme4 or nlme. Here is how I thought I’d code this in lme4.

```
# Tentative model - 
fit=lmer(logMossSize~ForestType*Treatment*Year+(1|Block/ForestType/plot.id/transplant.id), data=df)
anova(fit)
summary(fit)
```

I am not sure this is correct, or a good way to handle the repeated measures. Since forest type only has 2 levels, I am also not sure it is correct to include it as a random effect. If my understanding of mixed models is correct, this allows for random intercepts, but not random slopes. Any help or advice will be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Hi Mélanie, this is a good [intro](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial.pdf), if that does not solve your questions or if it's to basic I would be happy to help

Comment: Thanks @DerekCorcoran. This is a really well written explanation of mixed models. I am guessing I should consider adding in some random slopes.
What it does not cover however, and the part that really trips me up, is how to handle nested random effects on top of random intercepts and slopes. Any advice?